Can response file properties include variable substitutions?
I have a response file like this:
-p:Copyright="Copyright C KittenMittens $(Year)"

And MSBuild command like this:
msbuild.exe solution.sln -p:Year=2024 @responsefile.rsp

But the assembly copyright ends up with $(Year) anyway. Putting the same string in the .csproj file the $(Year) is properly substituted. I've tried different ways of getting the variable in the response file substituted but am now out of ideas. Anyone else have an idea how to do it?

The -property switch doesn't perform property expansion on the provided value. Moving the switch to a response file doesn't change that. You could pass Year and CopyrightOwner on the command line and in the msbuild code have <PropertyGroup><Copyright>Copyright C $(CopyrightOwner) $(Year)</Copyright></PropertyGroup>

Comment by @jonathan-dodds:

The -property switch doesn't perform property expansion on the provided value. Moving the switch to a response file doesn't change that.


Alternatives:

Add the property <Copyright>Copyright C $(CopyrightOwner) $(Year)</Copyright> to the project file (courtesy of jonathan)
Set the full property at MSBuild command like msbuild.exe -p:Copyright="Copyright ... 2024"

